# Where can I find the documentation for sigma.js?

Tags: sigma.js

I am trying to test the limits of sigma.js (v2) to determine whether it is a suitable option for our project.
From what I have seen in various sample applications it looks very promising. Unfortunately, I am unable to find proper documentation.

All I can find are demo applications and some (seeming rather outdated) Wiki subpages (i.e. for [Settings](https://github-wiki-see.page/m/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Settings)).

Basically, I need to know the feature set of SigmaJS, and I would like to not have to dig through the entire source code to do that ;)

What I am currently looking for:

- What global **settings** can I pass Sigma when I do... ?

  `const sigmaRenderer = new Sigma(graph, container, settings);`
- What node & edge properties are implemented in Sigma?

  For example, I can set the coordinates, size, type and image like this:

  ```
  graph.addNode("Node-A", {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    size: 10,
    type: "image",
    image: "my-image.png"
  })
  ```

  What else is possible? What other options for **type** are possible?
- Where can I find a list of supported event listeners? What is the model of the returned object?
- etc.

Is there an official, up-to-date documentation or wiki that I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Sigmajs is written in typescript, so a lot of information are directly available in types.

If you have an IDE that handles typescript, you see the auto-completion with what you can give to the constructor.

For the settings, you can take a look at this link https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/339be9ed274fcfb881ddd3585974ea7be46ca7dd/src/settings.ts#L34-L82

For attributes node, you can define :

```
x: number;
y: number;
image: string;
label: string | null;
size: number;
color: string;
hidden: boolean;
forceLabel: boolean;
zIndex: number;
type: string;
```

For events  :

```
"clickNode",
  "rightClickNode",
  "downNode",
  "enterNode",
  "leaveNode",
  "doubleClickNode",
  "wheelNode",
  "clickEdge",
  "rightClickEdge",
  "downEdge",
  "enterEdge",
  "leaveEdge",
  "doubleClickEdge",
  "wheelEdge",
  "clickStage",
  "rightClickStage",
  "downStage",
  "doubleClickStage",
  "wheelStage",
  "kill",
```

Comment: Using a typed language is not a replacement for a documentation. Auto-completion will not suggest the available events (as you have listed above), nor the available node types (as you have not listed above and are still unknown to me).
It is really unfortunate that you put all that work into building a library, but then don't show people how to use it.

Comment: We have written examples that are listed on the website (and readme) that you can execute on codesandbox, so it's the way to start. 
We tried to be exhaustive on those examples (ex : for events =>  https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/main/examples/events/index.ts )
We plan to create a website for documentation and it should comes in a couple of months. So far we tried many options, the last in date  was typedoc ( https://www.sigmajs.org/docs/ )  that generates a website from types, but it doesn't solve our issues about documentation.

Comment: @logisima any news on the docs? I really like the sigma package, but it is a pain to find out how to do certain things without proper docs